# Increase Azure SQL database Data Max size in azure powershell

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

In Prod environment for AZURE SQL database, I have S3 DTU and data max size is 10 GB. I want it to modify to 200GB,  which I want to do by azure powershell script via pipeline(as other team members don't have access to PROD, so a pipeline can help).

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

First, please [install the Azure PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.6.0)

Then, you can use the `Set-AzSqlDatabase` command as following:

```
Connect-AzAccount
$GB = 1024*1024*1024
Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "JackSQL" -ServerName "jacksql268" -DatabaseName "demodb" -MaxSizeBytes $(10*$GB)
```

---

**Update**

If you do not want to connect to Azure interactively, you can [sign in with a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-2.6.0#sign-in-with-a-service-principal-). This will be suitable for automation.